# React.useMemo() and Event Listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a REACT App using Hooks, and now I'm facing an issue when using `useMemo()` and some event listener. i've, prepared a simpler demo of my problem on CodeSandBox: here's the link → https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hertz-21jov?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.

Now, let me explain where's the problem: I have `buttonData` which is computed using `useMemo()`. Now, let's took a look into the console output:
[image]

At first, `buttonData` is computed on first render, and `buttonData.behavior` is equal to `test1`. Then, when I enter the button, inside `onMouseEnterButton` I use `setTargetDOM`: this will trigger `buttonData` to be recomputed, since `setTargetDOM` is one of its dependencies.
So far, so good:

1. In the console first line, we see that `buttonData.behavior` is `test1`;
2. In the second line we see that we enter `onMouseEnterButton`, and that right now `buttonData.behavior` is `test1`;
3. In third line we see that, since `targetDOM` has changed, we have computed again `buttonData`, and now `buttonData.beavhior` is equal to `test2`;

And now, here comes the problem, what I don't understand! I can somehow accept the fact that the fourth console line tells me that `buttonDat.behavior` is still `test1`, since we are still in the same function that changed `targetDOM` and thus triggered `buttonData` to change (even if I expected to see `buttonData.behavior: test2` even in the fourth line.

What's even worste is that, inside `onMouseMoveButton` I see `buttonData.behavior` equals to `test1`, and not `test2`..

The question is simple.. Why? I mean, I thought implementing this way I had `test2`, but I guess I'm missing some React Hook stuff right here.

Comment: Why don't you use button props instead of add/remove listeners?

Comment: This was a simpler example of my problem. In my real application, I add the event listeners to elements retrieved with `querySelectorAll`, which are rendered outside the Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onMouseMoveButton` and `onMouseEnterButton` capture `buttonData.behavior` on the first render and because you never update the event listeners they will always refer to the initial value of `buttonData.behavior`

What you can do is add `buttonData.behavior` to the dependencies array of `useLayoutEffect` and every time `buttonData.behavior` changes it will run the returned function and remove the previous listeners and add new ones

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [buttonData.behavior])
```

Also, state updates are asynchronous so you in line 4 you can't really `log` the updated state after you set it

```js
setTargetDOM(e.currentTarget);
// this will never the updated value because 
// the state updater hasn't run yet
console.log(buttonData.behavior);
```

Comment: Uhm, so you mean `const onMouseMoveButton = React.useLayoutEffect((e) => { ... })` ?

Comment: @Jolly No i mean just add `buttonData.behavior` into the dependencies array of `useLayoutEffect`, nothing else

Comment: Oh ok, got it!.. Yeah, it works, now I need to transpose the solution to the more complex project I have.. but thank you, I got what was the problem